# android api 26 and above not showing in visual studio 2013

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2013, xamarin.android

I just finished developing a basic app with visual studio 2013 and when uploading to google play store, it says the app must target api 26 minimum.
I have installed api 26 and 27 in my android sdk but it is not showing in my visual studio 2013. 
What is showing is android 7.1 api 25.[android api level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWGuf.png)

Comment: You most likely need a newer version of Xamarin.Android installed. What Xamarin Target levels are available (not the Android SDL target, but the Xamarin one)  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/android-api-levels?tabs=vswin

Comment: It is highly recommended to use Visual Studio 2017 to stay current with the latest Xamarin.Android releases. [You will need a minimum of Xamarin.Android 8.0 to support API 26.](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_8/xamarin.android_8.0/#oreo)